# object that have a row and column in data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, object, datagrid

Is there an object in a `WPF DataGrid` that holds the column and the row?

I thought it `CurrentCell` (**DataGridCellInfo**), but it holds only an object of the column.

I'm looking for an object in the DataGrid that holds the DataGridColumn and also holds DataGridRow, if there is something like that.

Comment: What is your final goal?

Comment: @Dennis. I need to get from object that inside the DataGrid objects of  row and column, I've been doing it separately. Just I'm wondering if there is already one object that holds both (row and column).

Comment: How about ItemsSource :) ?

Comment: `SelectedItem` doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: @ethicallogics. ItemSource its a IEnumerable object, it don't holds row and column.

Comment: @Dennis. you can look at cs of DataGrid, the SelectedItem it's a object. it not hold row and column.

Comment: What are you going to do with row and column, if you'll get them?

Comment: @Dennis. I already got them separately, I took out some data. My question is if you can get them in a uniform way.

Comment: `Datagrid.CurrentItem` gives you row & `DataGrid.CurrentColumn` gives you the column

Comment: @FarhanMukadam. I know that. I just asked if there is an object that holds them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was dealing with this too and I got the **indexes** of row and column this way:

```
DataGridCellInfo cell;

int columnIndex = cell.Column.DisplayIndex;
int rowIndex = mydatagrid.Items.IndexOf(cell.Item);
```

In case of getting the **headers** I went this way:

```
string columnHeader = cell.Column.Header.ToString();
string rowHeader = (((DataRowView)cell.Item).Row.ItemArray[0]).ToString();
```

I don't think it's the best way but it works and I didn't find any object that would gimme this info directly... if you get something better, tell me :]

Comment: It sounds good! I do not think there's a better way to do it.